# Angular 7 authorized with Gmail

Tags: angular, gmail-api, angular7

all am trying to do gmail authorized  in angular 7 using angular5-social-login. Anyway it works for me but I need to run the function on page load. I tried to call it in `ngOnInit` and `ngAfterViewInit` with the following error:

> Uncaught (in promise): TypeError: Cannot read property 'signIn' of undefined
>   TypeError: Cannot read property 'signIn' of undefined'

```
import { Component, OnInit, NgZone } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService, SocialLoginModule } from 'angular5-social-login';
import { GoogleLoginProvider } from 'angular5-social-login'
import { User } from 'src/app/commen/user';
import { CookieService } from 'ngx-cookie-service';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { ApiService } from 'src/app/api.service';
import { Router } from '@angular/router'
import { AppComponent } from '../app.component';


@Component({
selector: 'app-login',
templateUrl: './login.component.html',
styleUrls: ['./login.component.css']
})
 export class LoginComponent {
 constructor(
  public SocialAuthService: AuthService,
  private cookie: CookieService,
  private http: HttpClient,
  private _ApiService: ApiService,
  private _user: User,
  private router: Router,
  private app: AppComponent,
 public zone: NgZone

  ) {



if (this.cookie.get('email') != '') {

  this.router.navigate(['\home']);

  }
  }


    googlelogin() {
    let socialPlatformProvider = GoogleLoginProvider.PROVIDER_ID;
  this.SocialAuthService.signIn(socialPlatformProvider).then((userdata) => {
    if (userdata.email.includes('nagwa.com')) {

    this._ApiService.getRole(userdata.email).subscribe((res) => {


      this.cookie.set('email', userdata.email, 12)
      this.cookie.set('name', userdata.name, 12);

      if (res == "admin") {

        this.cookie.set('role', 'true', 12)
      }
      else this.cookie.set('role', 'false', 12)

      this.cookie.set('image', userdata.image, 12)
      this.router.navigate(['\home'])

    }
    )




  }
  else alert("please check with nagwa account")


}).catch(function (err) {

  console.log(err)

});
    }

 ngOnInit() {




    }
    ngAfterViewInit()
     {

   this.googlelogin();
   }

   }
```

Comment: From error it look like that SocialAuthService is null or undefined

Comment: yes it return with null i miss  something call auth2 when i try to call from  event but when i call from  click button it work  ?? @AnkurShah

Comment: try set timeout of 1000ms in ngAfterViewInit. if it works then you need to find a place where it works.

Comment: it work when i add  set timeout @AnkurShah but i try all page event not one work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Temporary solution for your problem

```
 ngAfterViewInit()
 {

   setTimeout (()=>{this.googlelogin()}, 1000);
 }
```